# Upload image fail when using mobile

Tags: php, laravel, image-uploading

I am trying to upload an image through the use of mobile and it is not working for some reason. I tried to upload from my laptop and it worked, and I have no idea what is happening here

Here is what is happening:

When I try to upload with my mobile device, it just redirect me back to the upload page and the image was not uploaded but if I were to use my laptop to do it, it worked and redirect me to /home page, can anyone help me out here, thanks a lot

Here is the controller I used to upload photo:

```
public function store1(Request $request){

   $this->validate($request, [
        'file' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
    ]);

   if ($request->hasFile('file')) {
        $image = $request->file('file');
        $name = $image->getClientOriginalName();
        $size = $image->getClientSize();
        $id = $request->user_id;
        $destinationPath = public_path('/images');
        $image->move($destinationPath, $name);

        $userImage = new UserImage;
        $PersonalInfo = new PersonalInfo;
        $userImage->name = $name;
        $userImage->size = $size;

        $user= PersonalInfo::find($id);
         $user->UserImages()->save($userImage);

}
       return redirect('/home');
    }
```

uploadImg.blade.php

```
                        {{  csrf_field()  }}
                    <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="{{$user->id}}">

                <div class="form-group">
                <label for="imageInput" class="control-label col-sm-3">Upload Image</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                        <input type="file" name="file">
                    </div>
                 </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-6-offset-2" style="padding-left: 30px">
                      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save">
                    </div>
                </div>
          </form>
```

Comment: are uploading same image on mobile ? test with same file on both sides

Comment: Yup tested with same file and still this problem occurs

Comment: is it on a remote server or on localhost?? show us view code too

Comment: remote server, but if I were to upload on my laptop it still works even in remote server @Sohel0415

Comment: check the image size you are uploading from mobile device and try with a small filename

Comment: The photos I tried to upload was 3.1MB, last week it was working fine where all the image uploaded was 3.1 or 3.2MB @Sohel0415

Comment: but your validation say that max size is 2MB, then how you expect to upload your image??

Comment: Wait that weird, now that you mention it your right, but last week I am able to upload images with 3MB or more, let me try removing it and see if it works

Comment: @Sohel0415 I tried removing this part, svg|max:2048', but still can't upload it

Comment: whats the error you get when validation fails?? I hope you are showing your validation message

Comment: There is no error coming out, it just return me to the upload image page

Comment: are you showing validation error messages on view??

Comment: No, I didn't show any message in the view, I have added my view inside the question, you can take a look what I did inside

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163611/discussion-between-sohel0415-and-blastme).

Comment: see this link and add the validation error https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#quick-displaying-the-validation-errors

Comment: @Sohel0415, can see in chat?

Comment: @blastme sorry??, i didn't get you.

Comment: Should we continue talking in the chat that you open? the part where you just gave me the link, more easier like this

Comment: @blastme ok, thats good